# Prove that a predicate is not computable

Tags: computability, recursion, sets, enumeration

Prove that the following predicate is not computable:
$P_e(n) = 
\begin{cases}
 1  & \textrm{if } \phi_n(n) = e \\
 0 & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Could someone explain how to approach this problem and what theorems could be useful here?

Comment: What is $\phi_n$? Is that the $n$'th Turing machine (for some enumeration of turing machines)?

Comment: My first guess is to use diagonalization techniques. Just like how we prove that the halting problem is undecidable

Comment: We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: What is $e$?  Please define all notation.  Where did you encounter this problem?  Please reference the original source of all copied material.

Comment: $\phi (n,n)$ (or $\phi_n$) might be the universal function with input n. I am not sure what exactly $e$ is since it was not defined. I found the exercise on some older lecture notes which are not complete. I think that @nirshahar might be correct that it is similar to prove the halting problem.